# WCF push notifications to subscribers.. over citrix

Tags: wcf, messaging, citrix, subscribe

I am trying to make a 'messaging service' to push messages to certain subscribing users all using an app on Citrix.

a user would generate a message (from within the app) that would be set to be sent to all or some or a subset of the other users (who subscribe at the time they load the app). the message would then popup (or whatever) from within the app itself.

is it possible to push messages in this setup? is this something that WCF is happy to handle.. is the fact that we use Citrix going to make it a huge pain?
I have had a look at the WCF callbacks, but not sure this will work over Citrix..

any suggestions answers to the above most happily received. also apologies for the rathy ropey description of the problem.

thanks

nat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found what i needed here

very useful

http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx